# Type mismatch (Error 13) when assigning Split Variant/String to Variant/Variant() Array

Tags: excel, vba

Why do I get a Type Mismatch error on the last line?

```
Dim LineArray()
Dim Line
Dim FilePath as String
FilePath = "X:\Path\To\File.txt"

Open FilePath For Input As #1
    Line Input #1, Line
Close #1

LineArray = Split(Line, vbTab)
```

LineArray is a Variant/Variant()

Line is a Variant/String

If I Dim them both as Variants I still get the error

Comment: Either `Dim LineArray` or `Dim LineArray() As String` since Split returns an array of type String.

Comment: It is good practise to always declare the type of your variables.  Ig upu are new to VBA then I'd recommend installing the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA.  The code inspections produced by Rubberduck will help you a lot in writing good VBA.

Comment: Hmm if I Dim them as Strings it works. Even assigning the LineArray to a 2D Variant Array works. I though LineArray had to be of type Variant to be able to assign it to a 2D Variant array. That's why I Dim:ed them both as Variants. My code works now, thanks!

Comment: @freeflow I always declare my variables, just in this case I thought it would help since variables are auto assigned as variants. But thanks for the tip on Rubberduck. I'll check that out!

Comment: Not just declare, but to make sure you always specify the type.  This is particularly important when posting on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the comments: `Split` returns an array of Strings.

So the correct syntax is

```
Dim LineArray() As String
LineArray = Split(Line, vbTab)
```

The VBA compiler knows that `LineArray` *will be* an array of Strings. However, as it is declared as dynamic array, it is not an array before you assign members to it. Usually, this is done using the `ReDim`-statement that reserves the necessary space for a certain number of variables of a specific type. When using the split-function, this ReDim (or something similar) is done inside the function.

Now `Variant` is a very special data type - it can hold *any* type of data. This can be an Integer, a String, a Date, an Object (reference), an Error, or the value `Empty` (which means nothing is assigned yet). And, it can even be an *array* of any datatype. You can get the information about what data it contains using the [function VarType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function).

**What you can`t do** is assign the result to an static array:

```
Dim LineArray(0 to 3) As String
LineArray = Split(Line, vbTab)
```

This will throw a compile error: Can't assign to array. The variable is not only defined, the memory is already reserved (in this case 4 Strings).

**What you also can't do** is to assign the result to an array of Variant. Why? Because the `Split` creates an Array of Strings. Now if you would assign this to an array of Variant, it would be possible to assign, let's say, a Double to the first element. However, the memory was reserved by Split to hold an String, so horrible things would happen to the memory.

```
Dim LineArray(0) As Variant
LineArray = Split(Line, vbTab)
LineArray(0) = 3.1415926      ' Ouch!
```

What would be needed is an instance that

- Reserve memory for n Variant variables and assign it to `LineArray` (n = number of strings returns by Split)
- Loop over all elements of the string array and assign the strings one by one to the variant array.
  Now while this is possible, no instance will do this for you. The Split-function creates and returns the String array. The assignment operator ("=") is capable to assign any value to a Variant, but is not capable to reserve an array and copy elements one by one.

Comment: Thank you for that awesome answer! I learnt a lot from it!